# How to Stop Listener's from Listening Message From Queue At Distributed Server Environment

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have listeners at 3 different server's.At the time of deployment when  i deploy app at server1 ,I want listener at server1 to stop listening new messages .But i want   Listeners at this server finish task which they are already processing.
My Xml Config is
Rabbit.xml

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost"     username="guest" password="guest" virtual-host="/"/>

<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection- factory="connectionFactory" reply-timeout="10" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:listener-container id="group"  connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrency="10" error-handler="genericErrorHandler" >
 <rabbit:listener  ref="MailListener" method="listen" queue-names="promoMailQueue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

To Stop Listener,I tried to stop SimplemessageListener.

```
   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;    
SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListener;
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer getContainer(){
  ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Rabbit.xml")
  messageListener           (SimpleMessageListenerContainer)ctx.getBean("group");
  return messageListener;
}

public void getContainer(){
   SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer =    getContainer();
  simpleMessageListenerContainer.stop();
  simpleMessageListenerContainer.destroy();
}
```

I execute this still i am getting hit on my Listener's,Please suggest a safe to do this.

Comment: It should work as the `stop` (`destroy` call `stop`) stop the consumers. As you set concurrency of 10, even after few second, your listener is called?

Comment: Even if i stop  SimpleMessageListenerContainer first ,Then send message to my queue , My Listener's start listening messages.

Answer (score 1):

Any messages already queued for the listeners will process before the stop. The default prefetch is 1 so each consumer (of 10) will have a maximum messages of 1 processed after the `stop()`.

So while, in general, only the current message being processed will complete, it is possible that some new messages might start; it all depends on the timing.

Increasing the prefetch above 1 makes this more likely.

Turn on DEBUG logging to examine the behavior.

Comment: Hi @Gary Russell , I called my api which destroy/stop SimpleMessageListenerContainer ,Then I push message's to queue,And i get hit on my listener. But i think i shouldn't get  as SimpleMessageListenerContainer is stopped.

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging and look at the message flow; all should become clear; if not, post the log somewhere (it's probably too big to post here).

Comment: Hi @Gary Russell, I set log level in rabbit.config file [ 
  {rabbit, [ 
    {log_levels, [{connection, debug}} 
  ]} 
].   But there is not important info i got in log.Please suggest if i made some mistake while turning on Debug Logging.

Comment: No; I mean to turn on DEBUG logging for category `org.springframework` in your application; using log4j or whatever logging framework you are using.

Comment: Hi @ Gary Russell Please find log at  http://pastebin.com/9aDvDKK0  ,Looking for help.Thanks

Comment: I need to see the complete log processing messages/stop/still processing messages (DEBUG for `org.springframework` category). That log does not help.